# Damaged file in acroread when include .pdf graphic with other graphics that are clipped

Tags: graphics, errors, pdf, acrobat

I came across a weird issue when you include multiple graphics files when one is a non-clipped .pdf and the others are clipped non-pdf. I'm running pdflatex and the resulting pdf is created and can be opened fine in Evince, but I can't open it in Adobe Reader, due to the error: "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired." Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=2in]{test.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=2in,trim=5 5 5 5,clip]{test.png}

\end{document}
```

I have a workaround which is to clip the .pdf graphic as well

```
\includegraphics[width=2in,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{test.pdf}
```

but I'm still curious to know what the problem is.

---

**EDIT:** Per @Heiko Oberdiek's comment, I tried to reproduce the problem with different image files which I could post for everyone. It seems there is no problem *most* of the time, I evidently stumbled on the perfect combination for disaster. Here's my new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

% A: Created powerpoint template with image as background. Then saved as pdf.
\includegraphics[width=2in]{test_powerpoint.pdf}

% B:
% \includegraphics[width=2in,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{test_powerpoint.pdf}

% C: Original creation of image using tikz and pdflatex
% \includegraphics[width=2in]{test_latex.pdf} 

% 1: Extracted eps image from test_latex.pdf using pdftops, 
% then converted to pdf using convert tool in linux
\includegraphics[width=2in,trim=5 5 5 5,clip]{test_latex_convert.png} 

% 2: Took snapshot of image in test_latex.pdf, saved graphic as .png
% \includegraphics[width=2in,trim=5 5 5 5,clip]{test_latex_snapshot.png} 

\end{document}
```

The images files can be downloaded: [test_powerpoint.pdf](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/485792/test_powerpoint.pdf),
[test_latex.pdf](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/485789/test_latex.pdf), [test_latex_convert.png](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/485790/test_latex_convert.png), [test_latex_snapshot.png](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/485791/test_latex_snapshot.png).

It turns out the ONLY combination that doesn't work is A1. (The generated pdf is [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/485804/test.pdf).) Everything else is fine, so I'm not even sure if it's the .pdf or the .png file that's the problem.

Comment: Can you put `test.pdf`, `test.png` and the generated PDF file somewhere for download?

Comment: If I substitute your input files with `example-image.pdf` and `example-image.png` (which are LaTeX demo graphics), the result *can* be opened fine in Adobe reader.