# Printed PDF has wrong colors and linethickness

Tags: color, printing, adobe

This error may be connected to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243532/damaged-file-in-acroread-when-include-pdf-graphic-with-other-graphics-that-are?rq=1) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319359/strange-printing-error-when-including-different-pdfs/319362#319362) posts.

My file is a presentation, created using beamer-class and LuaLatex.

The compilation works fine, there are no errors. I will try to create a non-classified MWE and post it later today.

When I open the created file in Acrobat (or any other viewer), everything looks fine. However, as soon as I print the file from Acrobat Reader (regardless if it is printed 'real' or to another PDF), the output is a bit colorless. The font is not black anymore but more like dark-gray. The colors seem washed out.

Additionally, line thickness and hatched lines are not shown correctly. (see images below)

Screenshots:

[image: Difference after PDF printing.]

On the left side, the desired output after compiling in Latex is shown. On the right side, the output after printing the file again with any kind of PDF printer. Printing it on paper results in a similar result as shown on the right.

This error seems to be Acrobat-only (using alternative viewers but the same printer-drivers results in much better results). But the question remains: Is there some way I could tweak my file to achieve good printing results from Acrobat as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was rather stupid:

The option in Acrobat Reader to "save ink and toner" seems to be applied to PDF-printing as well, resulting in lighter, grayer fonts and reduced line thickness.

Case closed.